# Why does cplex not assign the value to the variables correctly?

Tags: variable-assignment, cplex

I have this constraint:

```
  forall (j in J)      
    forall (i in I: macc [i][j] == 0)
 
    {    
     
  V10b: sum(m in M) y[i][j][m] == 0;
 

     }
```

where macc [i][j] is a matrix of values ranging from 0 to 20.
I have macc [7][2] == 0 so in output I should have y[7][2][m] == 0 forall m. But in output cplex assigns the value 1 to a random m. For example y[7][2][m==2] == 1. Assign well up to a certain point, then start making mistakes. What could be the mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default OPL CPLEX will relax some constraints if the model is not feasible. If you do not want this to happen, in the settings editor turn those options off

[image]

Comment: I tried to do this but now after run, no variable has value.

Comment: That will be because your model is infeasible, which was why CPLEX was relaxing some of your constraints.

Comment: In fact in relation to that constraint I have a slack value equal to 1. Can some input values be wrong or just the wording?